# How can I delete data using ODI procedure-12C

Tags: procedure

I am new in ODI and facing different issue while I am trying to delete data using procedure.

Steps I followed :

- Create a procedure where in source command we kept select query. `SELECT DOC_ID FROM SOURCE_TAB`
- In target command we kept delete query which suppose to delete only unmatched data from `TARGET_TAB`.
  `DELETE FROM TARGET_TAB WHERE TRAN_ID NOT IN (:DOC_ID)`
- But our concern is here, procedure executes successfully and its delete all data from target table where source and target table data has same.

Source table: `SOURCE_TAB`

```
DOC_ID NUMBER(10);
====
10
20
30
40
50
```

Target table : `TARGET_TAB`

```
TRAN_ID NUMBER(10);
====
10
20
30
40
50
```

NOTE: Source and target table data is sale. It should not delete any data.

Answer (score 0):

For this method ODI uses row by row method. For every DOC_ID from the source it executes command on target

```
DELETE FROM TARGET_TAB WHERE TRAN_ID NOT IN (10) 
DELETE FROM TARGET_TAB WHERE TRAN_ID NOT IN (20)
```

.....

Therefore it deletes all data

If source and target tables  are in  the same database, use single query to delete data.

```
DELETE FROM TARGET_TAB WHERE TRAN_ID NOT IN (SELECT DOC_ID FROM SOURCE_TAB)
```

Comment: Source and target DB is different in this case.